# Reactjs - toggle switches not working when using local array

Tags: reactjs

I have an update for anyone that is reading this....
I think I've found the issue - when you set a toggle switch to checked it's also set to READONLY. So I can't toggle the toggle switch now.

I have a toggle component of type checkbox in React.

`products` is a locally set array for testing purposes as `this.props.products`  is empty for now.

Through testing, I've noticed that if I use:
`selected={(products.indexOf(p) > -1)}` the toggles stop working. They display correctly but I'm not able to toggle them. They do not appear disabled or are set to disabled in HTML element.

```
     products=['ProdA', 'ProdB', 'ProdC];

     customerProducts.forEach(p => {
       content(): string[] {
       const toggles = [];
        if(isEnabled){
          toggles.push( 
            <ToggleComponent
              value={p}
              selected={(products.indexOf(p) > -1)} 
              onChange={this.props.onChange}
              disabled={false}
            />
           );
      }

     render() {
        {this.content()}
     }

    //TOGGLE COMPONENT
    render() {
    const {id, title, disabled, name, value, selected} = this.props;        
    return (
      <div>
        <fieldset>
          <div className="form-structure">                    
            <label className={!this.props.disabled ? 'checkbox-switch-label' : 'checkbox-switch-label checkbox-switch-label-disabled'}>
            <input id={id} type="checkbox" checked={selected} className="checkbox-switch" role="Switch" disabled={disabled} name={name} value={value} onChange={this.validate} />
            <span/>{title}
            </label>
         </div>
       </fieldset>
      </div>
    )}
```

I can see there is an invalid Event Listener in my dev Tools: dispatchDiscreteEvent
The toggles are appearing, are not visibly disabled, (there is no disabled attribute in the html element), but clicking them does not toggle them on/off.
Am I supposed to be setting 'disabled' against a state value instead?
I already have an onChange function elsewhere for getting the values.

Comment: What does the render() of your ToggleComponent look like?

Comment: What Jeremy says, you need to provide more code.

Comment: I've updated my question with more details

Comment: please add the `ToggleComponent` component code.

Comment: I've done so much testing, if I use a local array the toggles stop working

Comment: I figured this out. By setting DefaultValue in the component it went a long way to putting me in the right direction.